# Survey new questions don't show on form SP2013

Tags: 2013, survey, survey-list

I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere, though my searching has yielded no useful results.

I have a survey on a SP2013 site and need to add a question to the form (*should* be a simple task). To do this, I:

- Add a question via Settings > Survey Settings > Add a question, or Settings > Add a Question.
- Simply fill out the question to add with appropriate field type, etc., and click 'Finish'.

At this point I now see the new question within the Survey Settings page, however when I go to the survey form itself via 'Respond to this Survey', the question does not appear.

I understand that the built in survey is well, garbage, and it would be easier long term to simply create my own through other means. Unfortunately due to the fact that the survey has been used and users would like to preserve prior responses within SP, I cannot simply make another survey with the needed additional question.

I would appreciates any ideas/solutions to this obnoxious behavior. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Turns out when this survey was made some time ago, a custom newitem.aspx form was created and set to be the default newitem form for the survey list. As such, no new fields would reflect on it as the custom aspx file generated by SharePoint only captures the current instance of the list when it is created.

Apologies to anyone who might come across this answer with it not being of use due to the arbitrariness of a custom form existing. I suppose if you've exhausted all other avenues don't forget to check out if an old custom form exists, or take note of susan's great idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked if the survey have branching logic? if it has, this is why your questions do not show up. Branching survey has systematic redirection to a final question that closes the survey. New questions outside the branching logic process will not show up

Comment: Thank you, this is an excellent suggestion, and something that hadn't occurred to me. Unfortunately it is not my solution.